# Passport js isAuthenticated() returns false

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, passport.js, mern

So i am a beginner in MERN stack. Currently working on a project. I have used passportjs for authentication in expressjs. Now the authentication on login page (REACT) is done smoothly but when it reaches the next page it goes back to unauthorize and i cant access the data.

**CONTROLLER**

```
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import passport from 'passport';
import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local';
import { PoliceStation } from '../Models/policestation.model.js';

class PoliceController {
  constructor() {
    this.router = express.Router();
    this.initializePassport();
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }

  initializePassport() {
    console.log('Initializing passport')
    passport.use(
      new LocalStrategy(async (username, password, done) => {
        try {
          console.log('Incoming username:', username);
          console.log('Incoming password:', password);
    
          const user = await PoliceStation.findOne({ name: username, password });
    
          if (!user) {
            console.log('User not found');
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password' });
          }
    
          console.log('User found:', user);
          return done(null, user);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error in LocalStrategy:', error);
          return done(error);
        }
      })
    );
    
    

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
      console.log('Serialize User:', user.id);
      done(null, user.id);
    });
    
    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
      console.log('Deserialize User ID:', id);
      try {
        const user = await PoliceStation.findById(id);
        console.log('Deserialized User:', user);
        done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Deserialize User Error:', error);
        done(error);
      }
    });
  }    


  initializeRoutes() {
    this.router.use(
      session({
        secret: 'your-secret-key',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        
      })
    );

    this.router.use(passport.initialize());
    this.router.use(passport.session());

    // ...

const requireLogin = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Authentication Status:', req.isAuthenticated());
  console.log('User Object:', req.user);

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  }
};


// Inside your server route handling the login
this.router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    // Authentication successful
    const user = req.user;
    console.log('Authenticated User:', user);

    // Log session data
    console.log('Session Data:', req.session);
    
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful', user });
  } else {
    // Authentication failed
    console.log('Authentication failed');
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Login failed' });
  }
});


// ...



this.router.get('/checklogin', (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log('User is authenticated:', req.user);
    res.json({ loggedIn: true, user: req.user });
  } else {
    console.log('User is not authenticated');
    res.json({ loggedIn: false });
  }
});   
}

export default PoliceController;
```

**LOGIN.JSX**

```
const Login = ({ setLoggedInUser }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [name, setname] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    try {
      const username = name;
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/police/login', { username, password });
      const { user } = response.data;
      console.log('Login Response:', response);
  
      Cookies.set('userId', user._id, { expires: 7 });
      Cookies.set('token', response.data.token, { expires: 7 });
      setLoggedInUser(user);
  
      // Check login status after setting cookies
      const checkLoginResponse = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/police/checklogin');
      console.log('Response Data:', checkLoginResponse.data);
      console.log('Full Response:', checkLoginResponse);
      navigate('/home', { replace: true });
  
      if (checkLoginResponse.data.loggedIn) {
        // Redirect or perform other actions after successful login
        navigate('/home', { replace: true });
      } else {
        console.error('Login failed. Response:', checkLoginResponse.data);
      }
  
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login error:', error);
      console.log('Complete error object:', error);
    }
  };
  
  

export default Login;
```

**HOME.JSX**

```
const Home = () => {
  const [policeOfficers, setPoliceOfficers] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  console.log("This is cookie on home",Cookies)
  console.log("This is cookie id in home component",Cookies.get('userId'));
  console.log("Cookie TOken on page no 2: ",Cookies.get)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
    
        const userId = Cookies.get('userId');
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/police/officer/${userId}`);
        setPoliceOfficers(response.data.policeOfficers);
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
          setError('Unauthorized. Please log in.');
        } else {
          setError('Error fetching police officers.');
        }
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once when the component mounts

}

export default Home;
```

So i tried console logging and these were the results.

**FRONTEND CONSOLE**

```
Login Response: {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
Login.jsx:26 Response Data: {loggedIn: false}
Login.jsx:27 Full Response: {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
Home.jsx:10 This is cookie on home {attributes: {…}, converter: {…}}
Home.jsx:11 This is cookie id in home component 646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9
Home.jsx:12 Cookie TOken on page no 2:  ƒ (name) {
    if (typeof document === 'undefined' || arguments.length && !name) {
      return;
    }

    // To prevent the for loop in the first place assign an empty array
    // in case there are …
Home.jsx:10 This is cookie on home {attributes: {…}, converter: {…}}
Home.jsx:11 This is cookie id in home component 646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9
Home.jsx:12 Cookie TOken on page no 2:  ƒ (name) {
    if (typeof document === 'undefined' || arguments.length && !name) {
      return;
    }

    // To prevent the for loop in the first place assign an empty array
    // in case there are …
xhr.js:251 
        
        
       GET http://localhost:5000/police/officer/646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9 401 (Unauthorized)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:251
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:148
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:174
wrap @ bind.js:5
fetchData @ Home.jsx:19
(anonymous) @ Home.jsx:30
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Home.jsx:10 This is cookie on home {attributes: {…}, converter: {…}}
Home.jsx:11 This is cookie id in home component 646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9
```

**BACKEND CONSOLE**

```
User found: {
  location: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [ 53.4808, 2.2426 ]
  },
  _id: new ObjectId("646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9"),
  name: 'MDA',
  address: 'MANCHESTER',
  phone: 519255339,
  password: '12345678',
  __v: 5,
  policeOfficers: [
    new ObjectId("646e3bf76c974f42bcbb055d"),
    new ObjectId("646f67acdff8e98bf7fcf530"),
    new ObjectId("646fc7aa88960bcfdc00352a"),
    new ObjectId("646fc7b788960bcfdc003532"),
    new ObjectId("6473905b525377ad83c76d27")
  ]
}
Serialize User: 646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9
Authenticated User: {
  location: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [ 53.4808, 2.2426 ]
  },
  _id: new ObjectId("646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9"),
  name: 'MDA',
  address: 'Manchester',
  phone: 519255339,
  password: '12345678',
  __v: 5,
  policeOfficers: [
    new ObjectId("646e3bf76c974f42bcbb055d"),
    new ObjectId("646f67acdff8e98bf7fcf530"),
    new ObjectId("646fc7aa88960bcfdc00352a"),
    new ObjectId("646fc7b788960bcfdc003532"),
    new ObjectId("6473905b525377ad83c76d27")
  ]
}
Session Data: Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },
  passport: { user: '646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9' }
}
User is not authenticated
Authentication Status: false
User Object: undefined
Authentication Status: false
User Object: undefined
```